# Match iteration number to values of non existent Cartesian Product Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, cartesian-product

Lets say we have the following arrays.

`[1,2]` & `[1,2,3]` & `[1,2,3,4]`

Then let's say we want to loop through all ***unique*** possible combinations of this.

The results should look something like this.

```
        //     IP1  IP2  IP3
        //0     0  - 0  - 0
        //1     0  - 0  - 1
        //2     0  - 0  - 2
        //3     0  - 0  - 3
        //4     0  - 1  - 0
        //5     0  - 1  - 1
        //6     0  - 1  - 2
        //7     0  - 1  - 3
        //8     0  - 2  - 0
        //9     0  - 2  - 1
       //10     0  - 2  - 2
       //11     0  - 2  - 3
       
       //12     1  - 0  - 0
       //13     1  - 0  - 1
       //14     1  - 0  - 2
       //15     1  - 0  - 3
       //16     1  - 1  - 0
       //17     1  - 1  - 1
       //18     1  - 1  - 2
       //19     1  - 1  - 3
       //20     1  - 2  - 0
       //21     1  - 2  - 1
       //22     1  - 2  - 2
       //23     1  - 2  - 3
```

It should produce 24 different combinations that are unique.

I can generate an array like this using the following cartersian function.

```
function cartesian() {
    console.log("Running cartesian()...");
    var r = [], arg = arguments, max = arg.length-1;
    
    function helper(arr, i) {
        try{
            for (var j=0, l=arg[i].length; j<l; j++) {
                var a = arr.slice(0); // clone arr
                a.push(arg[i][j])
                if (i==max) {
                    r.push(a);
                } else
                    helper(a, i+1);
            }
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    helper([], 0);
    return r;
};
```

You would call this array something like this cartesian(...array_of_arrays) which uses the spread operator to send each array in the array as an argument.

The problem with this method is this uses a **large memory footprint**.  If the arrays start to exceed in the millions of values my applications start ***running out of memory*** and crashing.  So while I could use this and simply just point to an index and know what my values would be in the Cartesian array I can't do this with large arrays.

My goal is if I choose a number like `14` for the index that it will return an array with the values `[1,0,2]` but **without creating the array** to know this to save on memory.

I created another interesting scenario to show how this might be possible.  Let's say I have 3 arrays `[1,2]` & `[1,2]` & `[1,2]`.  Now every combination might look like below.

```
        //     IP1  IP2  IP3
        //0     0  - 0  - 0
        //1     0  - 0  - 1
        //2     0  - 1  - 0
        //3     0  - 1  - 1
        //4     1  - 0  - 0
        //5     1  - 0  - 1
        //6     1  - 1  - 0
        //7     1  - 1  - 1
```

Technically if we use number 5 we could assume the binary form of it and read the bits.

This would tell us that for iteration 5 without knowing anything else that simply by it being the number 5 that the resultant array has a `[1,0,1]` which is the **binary representation of 5 ironically enough**.  So if I had an array of nothing but pairs this technique could be used perhaps.  Maybe this is a clue to how to solve this though.

I'm not sure what to do **when the arrays are varying sizes** and not always binary pairs?

**To be clear I need a function that does not take an array, but instead is given 'start', 'end' & 'step' and can deduce from these what the array returned value would be from an index.**

Something like: `cartesianElementPosition([[start,end,step],[start,end,step],[start,end,step]],14)` and this should return `[1,0,2]` from my example with the 24 possibilities where start end step are the **rules describing how the arrays would** be create**d without actually creating it**

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this to extract the element

```js
const cartesianElementPosition = (data, position) => {

  const arrayLengths = data.map(([start, end, step]) => Math.floor((end - start) / step) + 1)

  const positions = arrayLengths.reduceRight((pos, l) => {
    const newRemain = Math.floor(pos.remain / l)

    return {
      result: [ pos.remain % l, ...pos.result],
      remain: newRemain
    }
  }, {
    result: [],
    remain: position
  })

  return positions.result
}

let data = [
  [1, 2, 1],
  [10, 12, 1],
  [0.86, 0.89, 0.01]
];
console.log(cartesianElementPosition(data, 14))
```

**update**
you can also try something like this

```js
class LazyArray {
  constructor(
    start,
    end,
    step
  ) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.step = step;
    this.length = Math.floor((end - start) / step) + 1
  }
  element(position) {
    if (position < 0 || postition >= this.length()) {
      throw new Error('out of index')
    }
    return this.step * this.position + this.start;
  }

}



const cartesianPositionAt = (data, pos) => {

  const arrayLengths = data.map(d => new LazyArray(...d).length)

  const positions = arrayLengths.reduceRight((pos, l) => {
    const newRemain = Math.floor(pos.remain / l)

    return {
      result: [pos.remain % l, ...pos.result],
      remain: newRemain
    }
  }, {
    result: [],
    remain: pos
  })

  return positions.result
}



let data = [
  [1, 2, 1],
  [10, 12, 1],
  [0.86, 0.89, 0.01]
];
let result = cartesianPositionAt(data, 14);
console.log("result below");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is you have to supply an array.  Is there a way to do this where you don't supply the array? The reason why is my array are in the millions if they are created making them unwieldy and causes memory crashes.  It's my fault for not specifying this so I will write a new question, but I need something where I supply a 'start', 'end', and 'step' that represents the arrays but without actually creating them for each array.  Then given that and an index it would give back the correct array.

Comment: I edited the end of my question to be more clear, thank you still for your answer, maybe I can figure out something with that idea still.

Comment: @JosephAstrahan I edited my answer to address your new requirement

Comment: Thanks! that is a really interesting answer also, I will have to compare this versus the solution I came up with and see what runs faster.  I will give feedback soon.

Comment: I like the extra protection you added also if it's out of index, seems very clean.  I will be testing this for sure to see if anything breaks or if I can add any suggestions for improvement.  Thanks again for this awesome function! I'm sure this will help a lot of people with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found an elegant solution this is very efficient.  This answer works well because its not creating any arrays just doing math and knowledge of the start,end,step values to account for how many entries make up the arrays.

```js
function cartesianPositionAt(arraysOfSES,position){
  let arraySizes = [];
  let returnArray = [];
  
    for(let i=0;i<arraysOfSES.length;i++){
    let end = arraysOfSES[i][1];
    let start = arraysOfSES[i][0];
    let step = arraysOfSES[i][2];
    let maxIterationsOfInput = parseInt((( end - start) / step + 1).toFixed(2))
    arraySizes.push(maxIterationsOfInput);
  }
  
  function recurse(r_arraySizes,r_position){
    if(r_arraySizes.length>1){
      var block_size=r_arraySizes.slice(-1)[0];
        for(let j=r_arraySizes.length;j>2;j--){
        block_size = block_size * r_arraySizes[j-2];
      }
      returnArray.push(0);//@JA - Assume skip value 0
 
      while(r_position>=block_size){
        r_position = r_position - block_size
        returnArray[returnArray.length-1] = returnArray[returnArray.length-1] +1
      }
      
      r_arraySizes.shift()//remove the first item in the array.
      recurse(r_arraySizes,r_position);
    }else{ //Final section of array to process
      returnArray.push(r_position);
    }
  }
  
  recurse(arraySizes,position);
    return returnArray
}
//[start,end,step]
let data = [[1,2,1],[10,12,1],[0.86,0.89,0.01]];
let result = cartesianPositionAt(data,14);
console.log("result below");
console.log(result);
```

Example of the code here via JSFiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/gentleman_goat66/mwur5jx9/163/